# "South up" coordinate reference system

Tags: coordinate-system

Are there any CRS that represents south up in a map?
Just like this:

[image: world upside down]

Comment: There are obviously many coordinate systems where Y increases downwards on the page, but they aren't generally designed for representing maps. If you create an SVG representation of a map in which North is shown at the top, then Y values will increase as you go South.

Comment: There are plenty of printed maps that are south-up; see https://www.flourish.org/upsidedownmap/

Comment: It would be fun to use a "negative meter" as a unit. I don't know if it's possible, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of any south-up projection (but it should be possible to modify an existing one to flip it) anyway for display or print purpose rotating the data frame or the print layout 180° should do the trick, alternatively you could rotate all label and text 180° then rotate the exported map south-up....

Comment: The question makes no mention of a "data frame" or a "print layout" or even a particular mapping technology. What are you referring to, and how do you know the OP's technology supports whatever you're talking about?

Comment: I was thinking on CRSs in proj4

Answer (score 9):

South Africa and Namibia have south-up coordinate systems. If you display a WGS84 shape of Africa with EPSG:2050, it looks like this:

[image]

Since it is a transverse mercator projection, you can not display the whole world with it, but you can build a similar mercator projection:

```
+proj=merc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=23 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +axis=wsu +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

which makes the blue marble looking upside down:

[image]

It even works for robinson:

```
+proj=robin +axis=wsu
```

viewed with a project CRS of sphere Robinson EPSG:53030

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using QGIS, you can rotate the map canvas and also the Print Composer by 180 degrees, which is a quick and easy way to achieve this affect, rather than having to alter the image after the fact or alter the labels - or alter the coordinate system for that matter:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No CRS does really define that north or south should be pointing up. You could have east pointing up with any CRS if You want to.